# Gmail spinning forever in Chrome, but fine in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

For a long time, Gmail does not work correctly in Chrome on my machine. I am able to read/compose email without any problems, but the spinning wheel is shown forever. In Firefox 4, the same Gmail account loads very quickly and the Gmail favicon shows up quickly.

I also can't attach files in Gmail on Chrome - is this related?

My system is Windows 7 64-bit and I'm using Firefox 4 / Chrome 11.0.696. No antivirus software is installed.

Comment: Same thing here actually on OS X with Chrome 12.0.742. Sometimes is finishes loading, sometimes it doesnt. Do you mean you can't attach it by drag & drop?

Comment: Have you ever tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome? I've found that fixes a number of issues, especially if you've gone through several automatic upgrades.

Comment: @slhck, i can drag and drop, but the file selection dialog wont open.

Comment: @Randolph yeah, re-installed several times. no go...

Comment: Are you using any GMail tweaking extensions or greasemonkey scripts?

Comment: FWIW, same problem here - running Chrome 11.0.696.60 on XP. Can't attach files, spinning wheel constantly when in Gmail. Seems to have started in the last week or so.

Comment: Me too. It spins for several minutes before finally stopping. I run 64-bit Win7Pro SP1, Chrome 11.0.696.65. Works fine on all my other Windows browsers, and on Chrome/Ubuntu. I only noticed this happening regularly in the last few days. I don't have problems with drag-n-drop, though.

Comment: On Chrome 5 this issue can be solved by enetring Gmail with another browser (like IE8) and in Gmail settings disable "Webclips". Then go in with Chrome and you will see it won't loop anymore. Unfortunatelt I can not answer this question cause it's protected by moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably due to an extension that blocks either ads or Java or flash. Do you have flashblock or adblock installed?

I have [clicktoplay](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/13/google-chrome-gets-click-to-play/) enabled in chrome which results in the constant spinning wheel. If I select the option to **Run all Plugins This time** then the wheel disappears.

Try disabling all Chrome extensions and see if that works.

Comment: That's sneaky and makes me want to use gmail less, even though I've used it since I got my invite WAY back when.

Comment: I have no extensions on Chrome at all, but it goes one reloading forever. It's funny that works with IE8 and not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try testing it and opening it in a incognito window in chrome?

That should remove any remove any plugins or cache etc.

Comment: Doesn't work on incognito window. Happens on Windows 7 64bit and Linux Mint 64bit. Reinstalling browser on Win7 doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer's date and time set correctly? I've found Chrome to be very sensitive to SSL certificate problems like expired and not-yet-valid certificates, and Gmail to just hang when there's an SSL failure.