# How to tell what Chrome is trying (and failing) to load?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

Lately my Google Chrome browser at the office pretty much always showing the "loading" spinner when I am using Gmail.

I haven't noticed any Gmail features that aren't working nor unloaded portions of the page.

I have AdBlock disabled on the domain but the company's outbound web proxy may be blocking something, so I can't be sure.

How can I tell what piece of the page Chrome is failing to load?

(Note that this question is related to [another similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/278630/gmail-spinning-forever-in-chrome-but-fine-in-firefox), but I am wanting to know specifically how to identify the failing load.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure if this will do everything you are looking for, but you chrome inspect element, then go to the network tab. You can then see what is running at that second (its bar will be growing to the far right). The link/action that is taking place will be shown on the far left.

Comment: That looks good to me. Thanks for the tip--I would never have thought to look behind the "Inspect element" features.